# installing MySql 5.7.16 stuck

Tags: mysql

I am installing MySql 5.7.16 first three steps sre completed but it stucks 2 hour has gone still not proced[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko3uh.png)

Comment: Questions on *how to use* software should be asked on superuser.com  because stackoverflow is for questions directly involving a programing problem. Besides that, With only this little information we cannot help anyways. Did you have a look in the windows event log? Any error log at all?

Comment: I am trying to add screenshots but fails